# Set image width in CSS but have height scale with width

Tags: html, css, image

I was wondering if there is a way to set a image width in css but have the height scale with that image so that it is not distorted. I have a lead image that i need to be 720px in width but the height doesn't matter I would just like the height to scale so that it is proportional to the width so that it doesn't look stretched.

```
.lead-image img{
 width: 720px;
 }
```

When I do this the width just gets stretched to 720px but the height stays they same, rather than scaled.

Edit: I figured it out, when I set the height to 100% than it works. Thanks

Comment: That should scale fine in most browsers. Can you create an example jsFiddle?

Comment: ..are you wanting something like this..? http://jsfiddle.net/Z2Emf/ Also.. just don't set a height on the image.. leave it at `auto`.

Comment: It looks like i needed to set the height to 100% and than it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely want to set your wrapping .lead image to a specific width and height, and then set your img styling like above to:

```
.lead-image {
    width: 720px;
    height: 300px;
}

.lead-image img {
   width: 100%;
   height: auto;
}
```

Unfortunately proportional image resizing is a pain in this respect without at least the wrapping container having a fixed height.

Answer (score 0):

By Setting the height to 100% also than it scaled. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

By Setting the height to auto the image width and height scale proportional

```
.lead-image img {
   width: 720px;
   height: auto;
}
```